# How to prove $(1+1/x)^x$ is increasing when $x>0$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $F(x)=(1+\frac{1}{x})^x$.

How do we prove $F(x)$ is increasing when $x>0$?

Comment: Have you tried the obvious avenue of looking at the sign of the derivative?

Comment: Perhaps by showing that log(F(x)) is increasing  for x>0?

Comment: Pursuing ofer's suggestion, you'll need to use the inequality $\ln(1+x)\ge x$ for $x\ge0$.

Comment: Combine the ideas of Henning Makholm and ofer, and look at the sign of the derivative of $\log(F(x))$.

Comment: @David: Double-check the direction of that "inequality". (I'm sure it was just a typo.) :)

Comment: oops, thanks...

Comment: @Meredith: Is this homework? If so, please read the [FAQ](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) regarding homework questions and update your post accordingly.

Comment: Hardy's "Inequalities" has an elegant proof using the mean value theorem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $h(x) = \mathrm e^{-1/(1+x)}(1+1/x)$ and note that for $x > 0$,
$$
h(x) = \mathrm e^{-1/(1+x)}\cdot\frac{x+1}{x} > \left(1-\frac{1}{1+x}\right)\frac{x+1}{x} = 1.
$$

Now, let $g(x) = \log F(x)$ and note that 
$$
g'(x) = \log(1+1/x) - \frac{1}{1+x} = \log h(x) > \log 1 = 0\>,
$$
and so we are done.

Comment: Please, where do you get this inequality from $
h(x) = \mathrm e^{-1/(1+x)} > \left(1-\frac{1}{1+x}\right) $ ?

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3379553/198592, Corollary.

Comment: Here's a proof of the relation I just asked you for: Starting from the obvious relation $1-\exp (-t)>0$ for $t>0$ the following integral $\int_0^{\frac{1}{x+1}} (1-\exp (-t)) \, dt =e^{-\frac{1}{x+1}}+\frac{1}{x+1}-1$ is also positive Q.E.D.

Answer (score 13):

There's an elementary approach for rational $x$. It suffices to prove that 
$$\left( 1+\frac{m}{n} \right)^n < \left( 1+\frac{m}{n+1} \right)^{n+1}$$ 
for $m,n$ positive integers. Whenever $0 \leq a < b$, we have $\frac{b^{n+1} - a^{n+1}}{b-a} = \sum_{k=0}^n a^{n-k}b^k < (n+1)b^n$ which rearranges to
$$[(n+1)a - nb] \cdot b^n < a^{n+1}.$$

Substituting $a = 1+m/(n+1)$ and $b = 1 +m/n$ into the above, the term in square braces (miraculously) reduces to $1$ and we get the desired bound. This is adapted from *Foundations of Mathematical Analysis* by Johnsonbaugh and Pfaffenberger.

Comment: Incidentally, substituting $a=1$ and $b=1+2/n$, another miracle occurs and the term in square braces reduces to $1/2$. From this, one can deduce that $(1+1/x)^x$ is bounded by $4$ (hence converges as $x \to \infty$).

Comment: And, of course, this shows the solution for all real positive $x$, since the rationals are dense in $\mathbb R$ and our function is smooth.

Comment: $b=1/(2n)$ is the correct choice to prove the boundedness by $4$.

Comment: @A.Γ. thanks for catching my mistake. I think there's also a mistake in your correction, though. Did you mean to say $b=1+1/(2n)$ is the correct choice?

Comment: Yea, right. "1+" was cut off. Finally, two wrong is one right =)

Answer (score 10):

It's enough to show $\ln(1+1/x)^x = x\ln(1+1/x)$ is increasing. Letting $h=1/x$, we can write the last expression as

$$\tag 1 \frac{\ln(1+h)-\ln 1}{h}.$$

We want to show $(1)$ increases as $h$ decreases. Now $(1)$ is just the slope of the line through $(1,\ln 1)$ and $(1+h,\ln(1+h)).$ And any concave function has the property that such slopes increase as $h$ decreases. Since $\ln x$ is concave, we're done.

Comment: Very elegant! $(+1)$

Comment: @Joe Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

$(1+1/x)^x$ is increasing equivalent to $x\cdot\ln(1+1/x)$ is increasing by taking natural logarithm. Which is equivalent to derivative being positive, which is showing that $h(x) = \ln(1+1/x) - 1/(1+x) > 0$.

And now notice $h'(x)=-1/[x\cdot(x+1)^2]$ is negative, so $h(x)$ is decreasing and minimal value is at $+\infty$, but $h(+\infty)=0$. So, $h(x) \ge 0$.

Comment: Your $h(x)$ is not the derivative of $x \log(x+1/x)$ or am I missing something?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain correct...it is the derivative of $x\log(1+\frac{1}{x})$, which is what he needs to determine. Not sure why you are talking about the function $x\log(x+1/x)$

Answer (score 3):

We have to prove that

$$F(x) = \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$$

is a strictly increasing function for $x>0$.

The derivative is

$$F'(x) = \frac{\left(\frac{1}{x}+1\right)^x \left((x+1) \log \left(\frac{1}{x}+1\right)-1\right)}{x+1}$$

Hence we only need to show that

$$\log \left(\frac{1}{x}+1\right)-\frac{1}{x+1}>0 $$

But this is obvious since the l.h.s. is equal to the definitely positive integral

$$\int_x^{\infty } \frac{1}{t (t+1)^2} \, dt$$

Comment: What is the motivation to have seen this integral? It would have never crossed my mind to consider comparing to an integral, and I still don't see how one would produce the integrand (just checking it required paper for me).

Comment: @ Trevor K The motivation was, of course, to find the proof I have given. And the integrand, well, I just "saw" it from looking at the inequality. BTW I find it's a pretty simple and elegant proof..

Comment: If you do say so yourself! Wow, I am astounded by your brilliance. If only I were as intelligent as you.

Comment: @ Trevor K To the matter, please.

Comment: Dear downvoter: please explain your decision. What is wrong with the proof? It would also be nice to know who you are.

Answer (score 2):

This proof is from theorem 140 from Hardy's *Inequalities*.
Let $f(x) = \ln\left[\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^x\right] = x(\ln(x+1) - \ln(x)).$ We refer to the mean value theorem: for each differentiable $g$,
$$
g(x + h) - g(x) = hg'(x + \theta h)
$$
for $\theta \in (0,1)$.

Applying the MVT to $g(x) = \ln(x)$, we get $\ln(x+1) - \ln(x) = \frac{1}{x + \theta}$. Since, $\frac{1}{x+\theta} > \frac{1}{x+1} $, we have that $\ln(x+1) - \ln(x) > \frac{1}{x+1}$, so
$$
f'(x) = \ln(x+1) - \ln(x) - \frac{1}{x+1} > 0.
$$
Hence, $f(x)$ and $e^{f(x)} = \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$ are increasing with $x$.

Comment: How did you arrive at f′(b)=ln(x+1)−ln(x)+1x>0 ?

Comment: It was a typo, sorry for the confusion. It is meant to say $f'(x) = ln(x+1) - ln(x) + \frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: How is ln(x+1)−ln(x)+1/x larger than zero?

Comment: It was yet another mistake. I'm very sorry that there are so many! I had the wrong derivative and also used the wrong inequality. It should be correct now.

Comment: Ah that's an interesting way of proving it.

Answer (score 1):

$f(t):=\frac{1}{t}\log(1+t)$ is decreasing for $t>0$, because it is smooth and its derivative is negative.

Its derivative is $f'(t)=-\frac{1}{t^2}g(t)$, where $g(t):=\log(1+t)-\frac{t}{1+t}.$
But, $g(t)>0$ for $t>0$, in fact, $\lim_{t\to 0}\ g(t)=0$ and $g$ is increasing.
$g$ is increasing because it is smooth and its derivative is positive: $g'(t)=\frac{t}{(1+t)^2}$.

Comment: Please correct this answer. $f(t)$ is *not* increasing in $t$ and $g'(t)$ is *not* negative, nor does it have the form you provide. The proof can be patched by considering these things carefully.

Comment: @cardinal thanks for your careful reading, I hope to have fixed all my mistakes.

Comment: I believe the derivative of $g(t)$ is still not quite right. :) (I believe, the whole denominator should be squared, i.e., $g'(t) = t/(1+t)^2$.)

Comment: I have made some corrections. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @cardinal Thank you very much for your correction. I was in a hurry today. Excuse me.

Comment: No apology necessary. Cheers. :)

Comment: Can we also prove this using similar technique?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287547/prove-that-1-frac-logxxx-is-monotonically-increasing-function-for-x

Answer (score 0):

The given inequality is equivalent to
$$ \ln (x+1)-\ln(x) > \frac{1}{x+1},\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  x\gt 0.$$
Let $f(t)= \frac{1}{t}$. Then,
$$ \ln (x+1)-\ln(x) = \int_1^{x+1} f(t)\  dt - \int_1^x f(t)\  dt $$$$
\ \ \ \ \ =\int_x^{x+1} f(t)\  dt $$$$\ \ \ \ \ge 1\cdot f(x+1) $$$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ =f(x+1) = \frac{1}{x+1}$$
since $f$ is a decreasing function.

The strict inequality can be obtained with a little more work; by breaking up the interval $[x, x+1]$ into two pieces -  such as $\left[x, x+{1\over 2}\right]$ and $\left[x+{1\over 2}, x+1\right]$  - and applying the same argument as above on each interval.