# show that if $n\geq1$, $(1+{1\over n})^n<(1+{1\over n+1})^{n+1}$

Tags: limits, inequality, exponential-function

I have derived the inequality if $k>1$,  ${n(n-1)⋯(n-k+1)\over k!} ({1\over n})^k<{(n+1)n⋯(n-k+2)\over k!} ({1\over n+1})^k$

But, my problem is how to use this inequality to prove that if $n\geq1$, $(1+{1\over n})^n<(1+{1\over n+1})^{n+1}$

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297916/proof-that-11-xx-is-monotonic-increasing and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83035/how-to-prove-11-xx-is-increasing-when-x0

Comment: Since it is an exercise from a reference book, on its question, i need to derive the formula from another proved formula. Therefore, i am questioning how to do it.

Answer (score 19):

use $AM-GM$,$$(1+\dfrac{1}{n})(1+\dfrac{1}{n})\cdots(1+\dfrac{1}{n})\cdot 1\le\left(\dfrac{n+1+1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$$

Comment: i didn't expect it to so simple (+1)

Comment: Yes, that's quite deviously clever. :-)

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{1+\frac{1}{n+1}}{1+\frac{1}{n}} = 1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}
$$

By Bernoulli's inequality:

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)^n \geq 1-\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}
$$

Putting it together:

$$\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n} \geq \left(1-\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right) = 1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}
$$