# Interesting function : $f(x)=\frac{\ln (\frac{x+2}{x+1})}{\ln (1+\frac{1}{x})}$ , $x>1$

Tags: calculus, functions, logarithms

Question :

Prove this function :

> $$f(x)=\dfrac{\ln \left(\dfrac{x+2}{x+1}\right)}{\ln \left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)},\quad x>1$$

is increasing.

I don't know how I solve by my effort is :

Derivative of $f$ is :

$$f'(x)=\dfrac{(x+2)\ln \left(\frac{x+2}{x+1}\right)-x\ln \left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)}{x(x+2)(x+1)\ln^{2} \left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)}$$

Then we will prove that $f'(x)≥0$ for any $x>1$

mean that But I don't know how to prove :

> $$(x+2)\ln \left(\frac{x+2}{x+1}\right)-x\ln \left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)\ge0$$

I need some ideas here if any one have.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I didn't check all the detail of your derivation, but

$$(x+2)\ln \left(\frac{x+2}{x+1}\right)-x\ln \left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)=\frac{x+2}{x+1}\ln \left(1+\frac1{x+1}\right)^{x+1}-\ln \left(1+\frac1x\right)^x≥0$$

and $$\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x$$ is an [**increasing function**](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83035/505767).

---

**EDIT** (*aimed to clarify any single step*)

We start from your last inquality that is

> $$(x+2)\ln \left(\frac{x+2}{x+1}\right)-x\ln \left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)\ge0$$

Now we multiply the LHS by a positive factor $1=\frac{x+1}{x+1}$

$$\frac{x+1}{x+1}(x+2)\ln \left(\frac{x+2}{x+1}\right)-x\ln \left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)\ge0$$

then we take the upper factor $(x+1)$ at the LHS inside the logarithm using that $n\log A=\log A^n$

$$\frac{x+2}{x+1}\ln \left(\frac{x+2}{x+1}\right)^{x+1}-x\ln \left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)\ge0$$

similarly, we take also the upper factor $x$ at the RHS inside the logarithm to obtain

$$\frac{x+2}{x+1}\ln \left(\frac{x+2}{x+1}\right)^{x+1}-\ln \left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)^x\ge0$$

then we use

- $\frac{x+2}{x+1}=\frac{1+x+1}{x+1}=1+\frac{1}{x+1}$
- $\frac{1+x}{x}=1+\frac{1}{x}$

to obtain finally

> $$\frac{x+2}{x+1}\ln \left(1+\frac1{x+1}\right)^{x+1}-\ln \left(1+\frac1x\right)^x≥0$$

Now we use that

- the function $g(x)=\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x$ is (strictly) increasing
- the factor $\frac{x+2}{x+1}>1$

then we can write the latter inequality as

> $$\frac{x+2}{x+1}g(x+1)-g(x)\ge \iff \frac{x+2}{x+1}g(x+1)\ge g(x)$$

which is trivially true indeed

$$\frac{x+2}{x+1}g(x+1)>g(x+1)\ge g(x)\quad \blacksquare$$

Comment: How you know the last result is $≥0$ ?

Comment: I gave a link for the proof! It’s very important to show that its lkmit is equal to e.

Comment: I mean my be :  $\frac{x+2}{x+1}\ln \left(1+\frac1{x+1}\right)^{x+1}<\ln \left(1+\frac1x\right)^x$ ??

Comment: I’ve just used $\log A^n=n\log A$ for the factor (x+1).

Comment: No I don't mean this I mean inequality see my commnt ?

Comment: @Ellen Ellen You might wish to see my solution.

Comment: I’m started from your last inequality to show that it is true. I’ve only used simple algebraic rules to get my last inequality which is true for the result shown in the link.

Comment: @EllenEllen I'm going to add some more detail to explain step by step.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze  Sorry but mine is one line :)! (taking the result for g(x), which is a foundamental fact). All the rest is only to explain trivial steps. Anyway I'll take a look also to your proof. Regards

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze You are not offensive indeed and me too. I've just expressed my idea. Regards

Comment: @gimusi You have just shifted the problem to the statement "$\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x$ is strictly increasing" but you did not prove it. Hence your proof is incomplete.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze I've added the reference for that result, which is a well known basic fact used to prove the existence of $e$ as limit.

Comment: @gimusi You can find a proof of your statement as a corollary in my solution.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze That's fine indeed. Let me observe that however the integral is a more advanced tool whereas the given fact about $g(x)$ can be proved by more basic facts.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

Here's a proof without expansions.

We wish to prove that

$$f(x) = \frac{\log (\frac{x+2}{x+1})}{\log (\frac{x+1}{x})}$$

is an increasing function, i.e. that

$$f'(x) = \frac{(x+2) \log \left(\frac{1}{x+1}+1\right)-x \log \left(\frac{1}{x}+1\right)}{x (x+1) (x+2) \log ^2\left(\frac{1}{x}+1\right)}>0$$

Since the denominator is positive we need to show that the numerator is positive, i.e.

$$(x+2) \log \left(\frac{1}{x+1}+1\right)-x \log \left(\frac{1}{x}+1\right)>0\tag{1}$$

Now the l.h.s. of $(1)$ can easily be shown to be identical to the integral

$$g= \int_x^{x+1} \log \left(\frac{1}{t}+1\right) \, dt\tag{2}$$

which is a positive quantity since the integrand is positive.

This completes the proof. Q.E.D.

**Corollary**

Using the same technique we can easily prove that

$$h(x) = \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$$

a strictly increasing function for $x>0$.

Indeed, the derivative is

$$h'(x) = \frac{\left(\frac{1}{x}+1\right)^x \left((x+1) \log \left(\frac{1}{x}+1\right)-1\right)}{x+1}$$

Hence we need to show that

$$\log \left(\frac{1}{x}+1\right)-\frac{1}{x+1}>0 $$

But this is obvious since the l.h.s. is equal to the positive integral

$$\int_x^{\infty } \frac{1}{t (t+1)^2} \, dt$$

**Original post**

For $x\gt0$ we have

$$f(x) = \frac{\log (\frac{x+2}{x+1})}{\log (\frac{x+1}{x})}\\=\frac{\log (\frac{x+1+1}{x+1})}{\log (\frac{x+1}{x})}\\=\frac{\log \left(1+\frac{1}{x+1}\right)}{\log \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}\\\simeq \frac{{\frac{1}{x+1}}}{\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{x}{x+1}=1-\frac{1}{x+1}$$

In the last line we have assumed that $x>>1$ and have used the expansion for small $|\epsilon|<<1$

$$\log(1+\epsilon)= \epsilon-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^2+ ...$$

Hence

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\simeq \frac{d}{dx}(1-\frac{1}{x+1})= +\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}) \gt 0$$

showing that the function is increasing. Q.E.D.

Comment: Nice solution! But I need method without equivalent ? If you can sir @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze

Comment: @Ellen Ellen In the edit to my solution I have given a proof without expansions.

Comment: It seems fine! But really I don't agree that it is simpler! Sorry