# $(\frac{x}{x+1})^x$ decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

I want to show that $f(x) = \left(\dfrac{x}{x+1}\right)^x$ is decreasing for $x > 0$; this is clear from plotting its graph. Taking its derivative,

$$f'(x) = \frac{x^x}{(x+1)^{x+1}}\left(1+(x+1)\log\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)\right).$$

So we need to show that $1+(x+1)\log\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right) < 0$, which seems to require taking another derivative. Is there an easier way to show that $f(x)$ is decreasing?

Comment: just use $\ln(1+x) < x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By taking a derivative, you can easily show that

$$\log(1+y) \le y$$

for all $y > -1$, with equality iff $y=0$ (this is a standard inequality). In particular, since $-1<-\frac{1}{x+1}<0$,

$$\log\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right) = \log\left(1 - \frac{1}{x+1}\right) < - \frac{1}{x+1}.$$

Therefore

$$1+(x+1)\log\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right) < 1 + (x+1)\cdot\frac{-1}{x+1} = 0.$$

Answer (score 3):

Use the fact that
$$
\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^x=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x} \, .
$$
Does the denominator look familiar to you?

Comment: Ah, yes, its limit is $e$... but now, why is the denominator increasing (without taking the derivative again)?

Comment: @tarthoe: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83035/how-to-prove-11-xx-is-increasing-when-x0) question help?

Comment: At the link you gave, I added an answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83035/how-to-prove-11-xx-is-increasing-when-x0/4186249#4186249.

Comment: @tarthoe: See zhw's answer—I like it very much.

Comment: Thank you to both!

Comment: @tarthoe: I'm glad I could help. Let me know if you have any questions.