# Let $f(x)=\left(1+\dfrac1x\right)^x$ and $g(x)=\left(1+\dfrac1x\right)^{x+1}$ then comment about the increasing/decreasing nature of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $f(x)=\left(1+\dfrac1x\right)^x$ and $g(x)=\left(1+\dfrac1x\right)^{x+1}$, both $f$ and $g$ being defined for $x\gt0$, then comment about the increasing/decreasing nature of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

$$f(x)=e^{x\ln\left(1+\dfrac1x\right)}\\f'(x)=\left(1+\dfrac1x\right)^x\left(\frac{x}{1+\frac1x}\cdot-\frac1{x^2}+\ln\left(1+\dfrac1x\right)\right)\\f'(x)=\left(1+\dfrac1x\right)^x\left(-\frac1{x+1}+\ln\left(1+\dfrac1x\right)\right)$$

Not able to determine the nature of $f(x)$ from this.

Also, $$g(x)=f(x)\left(1+\frac1x\right)\\g'(x)=f'(x)\left(1+\frac1x\right)+f(x)\cdot-\frac1{x^2}$$

Even if I know the nature of $f'(x)$, not sure how to comment about $g'(x)$.

Comment: To show $f$ is increasing, you might like to see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83035/how-to-prove-11-xx-is-increasing-when-x0/4186249#4186249

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sign of $f'(x)$ is the same as the sign of

$$\ln\left(1+\frac1x\right) - \frac{1}{x+1} = \ln\frac{x+1}{x} - \frac{1}{1+x}$$

So all you have to do is examine this sign. Now, you can first play around and plug a couple of values of $x$ into the expression. Try plugging in $x=0.1, 1, 10, 100$. You might notice that in all cases, you get a positive result, which should give you the idea that the expression will likely always be positive.

Now, of course, you still have to **prove** that the expression is positive, but at least now you have an idea of what to aim for.

---

To prove the expression is always positive, the way I would go about it is by proving the following:

1. The function $x\mapsto \ln\left(1+\frac1x\right) - \frac{1}{x+1}$ is **decreasing**.
2. The limit of the function as $x\to \infty$ is $0$.

If you prove both points above, you can conclude the function $x\mapsto \ln\left(1+\frac1x\right) - \frac{1}{x+1}$ is always positive.

Comment: Thanks. So, $f'(x), \left(1+\frac1x\right), f(x), \frac1{x^2}$ are positive. From this, can we comment about $g'(x)$?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty}g'(x)=0$. Also, $g'(x)=f'(x)(-\frac1{x^2})+f''(x)(1+\frac1x)+f'(x)(-\frac1{x^2})+f(x)(\frac2{x^3})$. First three terms are negative. Last term is positive. So, not able to conclude. Am I doing it right?

Comment: @aarbee $g(x)=f(x)\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$. You know that $f$ is a nonnegative decreasing function, and $x\mapsto 1+\frac1x$ is a nonnegative decreasing function. The product of decreasing functions is...

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Comment: Hi. In your last comment, you have written $f$ is a nonnegative decreasing function. Do you mean it? Or do you mean it's an increasing function? Haven't we proved that $f$ is an increasing function since $f'\gt0$?

Comment: Also, are we getting $g(x)=$ product of an increasing and deceasing function? Can we conclude anything from this?

Comment: @aarbee Yeah, it was a typo, $f$ is an increasing function. It was a typo because the *derivative* is decreasing. My bad.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying but sorry I am still not clear about $g(x)$, which is a product of an increasing and a decreasing function. Also, I have written $g'(x)$ above. Can we conclude anything from this?