# Elementary proof that $(1+1/x)^x$ is increasing for $x \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

All similar proofs I could find show that $(1+1/n)^n$ is increasing for positive integers values of $n$ only, or show that the derivative of $(1+1/x)^x$ is positive for all $x \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

I'm looking for a proof that $x<y \implies (1+1/x)^x < (1+1/y)^y$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ that doesn't use the derivative of $a^x$ nor the derivative of $\log_a (x)$

My attempt so far:

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that $x<y$. Let

$$
\begin{align}
J&= \frac {\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)^y}{\left( 1+ \frac{1}{x} \right)^x}\\
&= \frac {(\frac{y+1}{y})^x(1+\frac{1}{y})^{y-x}}{(\frac{x+1}{x} )^x}\\ 
&= {(\frac{xy+x}{xy+y})^x(1+\frac{1}{y})^{y-x}} \\
&= {\left(1 - \frac{y-x}{xy+y}\right)^x\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)^{y-x}}
\end{align}
$$

Showing that $\left(1 - \frac{y-x}{xy+y}\right)^x > \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)^{y-x}}$ is what I'm missing

Comment: Some of the proofs given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83035/how-to-prove-11-xx-is-increasing-when-x0) seem suitable.

Comment: An approach by taking logarithms could be a possibility, but you have to assume inequalities about the natural logarithm

Comment: So show us what you’ve tried and where you get stuck.

Comment: Edited the question to add that @TedShifrin

Comment: I managed to prove the missing part with Bernoulli's inequality

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, since you know Bernoulli's inequality, then for $0<x<y$, note:
$$\left(1+\frac1y \right)^{\frac{y}x}>1+\frac{y}x\cdot\frac1y=1+\frac1x$$

Comment: That just hides the question for how to prove Bernoulli for real exponents. There are easy proofs  of Bernoulli for the exponents which are positive integers (induction.)

Comment: Basically the binomial theorem is all you need for integer exponents, but the question becomes harder for real exponents because, even when the infinite binomial converges, it has negative terms.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews At the core of the issue, irrational exponentiation definition itself will require tools beyond "elementary", like limits and continuity, and then those tools are enough to extend Bernoulli's inequality (using weighted AM-GM, or concavity of log, say) from rational exponents to all real ones.

Comment: You might just prove $(1+x)^p\geq (1+xp/q)^q$ for $p,q$ positive integers, $p\geq q,$ and then use continuity of $(1+x)^r$ in $r$ for irrational $r.$ You don't need logarithms, though they definitely make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to prove the part I'm missing if I add the further assumption that $x < y < 2x$.

$y - x < x$ and $\frac{x}{y - x} > 1$

Let $K = \frac{y-x}{xy+y} = \frac{y-x}{(x+1)y}$ and $\alpha=y-x$

$K = \frac{\alpha}{(x+1)(x+\alpha)} = \frac{\alpha}{x^2+\alpha x+ x + \alpha}$

$\frac{1}{K} = \frac{x^2+\alpha x+ x + \alpha}{\alpha} = \frac{x^2+\alpha x+ x}{\alpha} + 1 >1$ and $0 < K < 1$

Since $-1 < -\frac{y-x}{xy+y} < 0$ and $\frac{x}{y-x} > 1$, we can use [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality).

$(1-\frac{y-x}{xy+y})^{\frac{x}{y-x}} > 1 - (\frac{y-x}{xy+y})(\frac{x}{y-x}) = 1 - \frac{1}{y+1} = \frac{y}{y+1}$

$(1-\frac{y-x}{xy+y})^x = \Big((1-\frac{y-x}{xy+y})^{\frac{x}{y-x}} \Big)^{y-x} > (\frac{y}{y+1})^{y-x} = \frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{y})^{y-x}}$

Therfore, $\frac {(1+\frac{1}{y})^y}{( 1+ \frac{1}{x} )^x} = {(1 - \frac{y-x}{xy+y})^x(1+\frac{1}{y})^{y-x}} > 1$ and $(1+\frac{1}{y})^y > ( 1+ \frac{1}{x} )^x$

Comment: Interesting, but you certainly show very easily that $(1+ \frac1{2x})^{2x}> (1+\frac1x)^x$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=x\log(\frac{x+1}{x})\Rightarrow f'(x)=\log(\frac{x+1}{x})-\frac{1}{1+x}\geq 0$$ from $\log y\leq y-1$ applied to $y=\frac{x}{x+1}.$

Comment: The question asks specifically to avoid the derivative of log.